# How I can make this code better

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I have fields like

> variable1,variable2,variable3....etc

and  my conditions are

```
if(variable1 != null && variable1 != 0 )
  myobject.setFirstValue(variable1);

if(variable2 != null && variable2 != 0 )
 myobject.setSecondValue(variable2);

if(variable3 != null && variable3 != 0 )
 myobject.setThirdValue(variable3);
```

Like this I have nearly 15 to consitions. Is there any way to write all these     conditions in a simple way.The variable names are not exactly same what I posted .    They are  different from what I posted.

Comment: Do you really need 15 variables rather than an array? And do you really want to call `setFirstValue` multiple times if multiple variables are non-null and non-zero?

Comment: what is the nature of your program ? what exactly are you doing with those variables ?

Comment: i am sending like state ,city ,street ,name values.I need to set those values if not null

Comment: @ Jon Skeet if i put in list or array  how i know which variable i need to set which setter method

Comment: You can use reflection but this can turn to be a bit nasty if not used properly. Highly depends on the real variable names and setter names

Comment: @JonSkeet Skeet how i can do with list

Comment: @PSR: Without more information, it's very hard to help you. The more effort you put into the question, the better the answers are likely to be. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet Skeet i really thought that this is enough information.I dont know what information is needed for u.Please can u tell me.

Comment: @PSR: Well now that you've *changed* the question, it's clearer. When you were setting the same property in three cases, that was different.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry i posted by mistake first time.I am really sorry.i updated my question.Can u give a best way for that

Comment: @JonSkeet the answers posted is ok. But is there any best way to do this

Comment: @JonSkeet please give a reply for me if you are free

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start with ...

```
if (notNullOrZer0(variable1)) {
   ...
}

private boolean notNullOrZero(Integer x) {
    return x != null && x != 0;
}
```

Then maybe put all these variables in a `List<Integer>` ... it depends on how the rest of your code is structured ...

Comment: i updated my question.Please see it once.I posted some mistake

Comment: if i put in list how i know which variable i need to set which setter method

Comment: Are all your variables the same type?

Comment: So you have a few variables which you want to construct an object out of? Or are you updating an object? How many variables?

Answer (score 5):

you can create a method `isNotNullorequalsZero` which checks not null and not equals zero

```
private boolean isNotNullorequalsZero(Integer value){
     return value != null && value != 0;
}
```

and you use that -

```
if(isNotNullorequalsZero(variable1) )
  myobject.setFirstValue(variable1);

if(isNotNullorequalsZero(variable2) )
 myobject.setFirstValue(variable2);

if(isNotNullorequalsZero(variable3) )
 myobject.setFirstValue(variable3);
```

Comment: Why the boilerplate code `return true..false`. you could change your code by: `return value != null && value != 0;`;)

Comment: +1 for your answer.It is also correct.But i can accept only one answer

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the variables in an array and use a for loop to check the condition and set the values in `myobject.setFirstValue(array[index]);`

Comment: but my setter methods are not same.How i can set

Answer (score 0):

either modify `setFirstValue` method as

```
void setFirstValue(Integer var){
if(var !=null && var !=0) {
//current logic of setFirstValue
}
}
```

or if not possible to modify it, create a wrapper call as (**return type boolean to notify user if call fails**)

```
boolean checkAndSetFirstValue(Integer var) {
    if(var !=null && var !=0){
        setFirstValue(var);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But you are hiding the fact that if something is wrong the caller will not be notified about it. You should throw an exception in such case

Comment: yes thnx for pointer, but i would rather prefer alternate approach as i edit the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a method called something like `copyIfNonZero`, and it would probably look like this:

```
public void copyIfNonZero(MyObject myObject, Integer value) {
    if (value != null && value != 0) {
        myObject.setFirstValue(value);
    }
}
```

And current code would be reduced to

```
copyIfNonZero(myobject, variable1);
copyIfNonZero(myobject, variable2);
copyIfNonZero(myobject, variable3);
...
```

Or even put the variables in a `Collection` and iterate over that:

```
Collection<Integer> values = .....
for(Integer value : values) {
    copyIfNonZero(myObject, value);
}
```

Comment: As it was in the first version of the question... :) But indeed, with the updated question, this approach isn't particularly useful.

Comment: oh, didn't see the first version :)

Answer (score 0):

If this is something that really occurs frequently in your code and you want to encapsulate this behaviour and avoid to repeat it, I would do something like that :

In a tools or utils class, create a static method :

```
public static void setPropertyIfNonNullNorZero(Object target, String propertyName, Integer value){

    //use some reflection tooling here, or write the whole thing yourself... I am  using commons.beanutils here

    if(value != null && value != 0){
        BeanUtils.setProperty(target, propertyName, value);
    }

}
```

This code assumes that your target object (myObject) respects the bean conventions (basically consitent getters and setters naming) and the the value is always an Integer.

Then use it like this :

```
Tools.setPropertyIfNonNullNorZero(myobject, "thirdValue", variable3);
```

Comment: what happens when you refactor a property name?

Comment: Of course, if you rename a property you have to change the property name manually in the method call(s), unless your refactoring tool is smart enough to detect these indirect references... It is the same as many other cases where beans properties are referenced by their name and not direct calls to the getter method by java code (e.g. HQL / JPAQL, JSP/JSTL, etc.)